# while loop with efficient progressive sum

Tags: python

I have a while loop to sum progressive rows of a file, that contains 7 columns like this:

CODES DISTANCE NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 NUM4 NUM5 NUM6

I would create a new array, that contains all the columns of the origin file, but rows until the progressive sum of different columns is at least 20. I create this codes, but i don't obtain the correct result:

```
network=()
cont=0
sum=0
anagrafica=np.insert(anagrafica, 8,0, axis=1)
while sum>=20:
    if anagrafica[cont,8]==0:
        network=np.append(network, (anagrafica[cont,:))
        sum=sum+network[2]
        anagrafica[cont,8]=1
        cont=cont+1
```

Comment: Shouldn't is be : `while sum<20`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "i don't obtain the correct result" is not a useful description of your problem - you should post a _complete_ verifiable example (your code doesn't include the definition of `np` so it's impossible to test it), and the expected and actual results. This being said, as written, your code will never enter the while loop obviously (cf Dominique's comment).